# Why does accessing an initialised array cause a segfault?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, compiler-construction, elf

I'm making a compiler for brainfuck and I've made the ELF header and 2 program headers, the relevant header is this:

```
Program_Header dataHeader =
    {
        1,                                                  // p_type (loadable segment)
        sizeof(ELF_Header) + 2 * sizeof(Program_Header)     // p_offset
        + machineCodeLength,                                // 
        0x0804a000,                                         // p_vaddr (virtual address)
        0x0804a000,                                         // p_paddr (unused)
        0x0,                                                // p_filesz (size in file)
        0x10000,                                            // p_memsz (size in memory)
        6,                                                  // p_flags (1=X 2=W 4=R)
        0x1000                                              // p_align
    };
```

and the compiled ELF file segfaults:

```
0:  31 f6                   xor    esi,esi
2:  31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
4:  31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
6:  31 c9                   xor    ecx,ecx
8:  31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
a:  66 46                   inc    si
c:  b0 01                   mov    al,0x1
e:  8a 9e 00 a0 04 08       mov    bl,BYTE PTR [esi+0x804a000]
14: cd 80                   int    0x80
```

I'm wondering why that happens when i define the data segment and access memory from within it

I have tried initialising the memory from the final binary file by adding extra null bytes at the end, i got it to work once but it stopped working and hasn't worked since

Comment: There's no C code here, why that tag?

Comment: `p_filesz = 0x0` tells the kernel to map zero bytes from this page, just zero-fill to the end of `p_memsz` like a `.bss`.  Use a debugger attached to your process to see what's going on when it segfaults.  You haven't show any other details about how you're creating an executable.  Does it run correctly if you don't include that memory access?  What does `strace ./a.out` say?

Comment: It's very suspicious that your disassembly shows the instructions starting at address `0`.  Unless you're actually creating a PIE (ET_DYN shared object), objdump should know the actual virtual address that's hard-coded into an ELF executable where the .text section will be mapped.  If that's `0`, it's below `mmap_min_addr` so `execve` will fail. 
 https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr

Comment: Also, doesn't `p_offset % 4096` have to match `p_vaddr % 4096` or something?  (So pagecache pages can be mapped into user-space.)  Or does that not apply when `p_filesz` is `0`, so the kernel just zero-initializes out to `p_memsz`?  (This is how linkers implement a `.bss` section as being space past the end of `.data` if there is one.)  So it's only initialized in the sense of zero-initialized, not with any data from the file.

Comment: @PeterCordes strace outputs execve("./app", ["./app"], 0x7ffeb9a714e0 /* 69 vars */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
what debugger would you recommend for this because i dont know much about debugging

Comment: @PeterCordes the disassembly is from a website, i just pasted the machine code from the elf file as i dont need an advanced disassembler for a program with 22 bytes of machine code and no loops (the file im compiling is just a single pointer increment)

Comment: `gdb` is good; useful commands include `starti` to stop before executing the first user-space instruction of a newly-execed process.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  But your executable doesn't even execute, so it's not instructions inside the binary that are faulting, it's execve itself because the kernel doesn't like your ELF headers.  Use `readelf -a` to examine it. (strace actually shows execve returning -EINVAL, but I know that some execve errors only get detected after the kernel has destroyed too much of the old process to return.  That might be what this is)

Comment: `objdump -drwC -Mintel` output will show you the virtual address from your headers.  But IIRC that only works if your program has section headers at all.  If you just wrote program headers, tools based on GNU Binutils (like objdump and GDB) can be less convenient to use.  GDB will still work in disassembly mode, though.  FASM can create binaries with no section headers, so you might google about how to debug those.

Comment: `llvm-objdump -DrwC -Mintel` will disassemble whole program segments if there aren't section headers, calling it a "section" named `PT_LOAD#0` (for the first segment).  You can put some NOP padding before your actual code so disassembly gets back into sync before it, in debug builds.  And yeah, I just re-checked that GDB works on a running process with no section headers, using disassembly mode.  (`layout reg` / `layout next`)  It's inconvenient that you can't scroll backwards in the disassembly pane because it doesn't have a start point to disassemble from.

Comment: FASM source for a minimal executable that just exits: `format  ELF executable 3` / `entry _start` / `segment readable executable` / `_start:` / `mov eax, 1` `int 0x80`.  Build as `fasm fasm-example.asm`.  On my system, it makes a 91-byte ELF executable for 32-bit mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes the following fasm code segfaults:
```format ELF executable 2 /
entry _start /
segment readable executable /


_start: /

xor esi, esi /
xor eax, eax /
xor ebx, ebx /
xor ecx, ecx /
xor edx, edx /

inc si /
mov al, 0x1 /
mov bl, [esi + array] /
int 0x80 /

array rb 0x10000
```
the output is pretty much the same as my program but with 1 less program header (the one mentioned in the post is missing im guessins)

Comment: `format ELF executable 2` is a NetBSD ELF executable.  Are you on NetBSD? On my Linux desktop, `strace` shows execve returning `-EFAULT` and then the process dying with SIGSEGV.  But surprisingly it still fails to even execve with `format ELF executable 3`.  It works without the array and the instruction that references it, but even having a second `section readable` with an `rb 1` makes it fail to execve.  Not sure from the `readelf -a` output what's wrong, perhaps that the address isn't aligned to the `align`?

Comment: According to [fasm forum](https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=3689) the last segment needs to be writable. Verified here, adding a writable section makes it work.

Comment: Actually that's not quite right, but putting the `array rb 0x10000` into a writable segment does fix it. I suspect it is because fasm cleverly optimizes the `rb` away if it's the last thing and just sets the virtual size larger. The kernel apparently does not like that in executable segments. If you put something after the `array` that will force fasm to emit the zeroes and that makes the kernel happy even if it's in the same segment as the code.

Comment: While the code in the question does use the same virtual size trick, it seems to be a writable segment which should theoretically work. Hard to troubleshoot without having access to the binary or at least a full `readelf` output.

Comment: @Jester: Executable or not doesn't seem to matter, just writeable or not.  My kernel (6.5.9) didn't like the binary FASM 1.73.31 made with a non-executable read-only segment (`segment readable`) with trailing `rb 1`, but `foo: db 0` was fine.  And making it `readable writeable` made `rb 1` work.  For the OP's problem, `p_vaddr - p_offset` is probably not a multiple of 4K, so it might be rejecting based on that even though `p_filesz` is 0.